# Is it dangerous to disassemble malware in IDA?

Tags: ida, malware

If I were to disassemble a malware sample in IDA without being in a VM, is there any way I can infect my machine?

Comment: Will reading a text on how to mix acid and zinc sulfide stink up your house?

Comment: @Jongware: Your brain doesn't contain buffer overflow vulnerabilities and integer wrap vulnerabilities that could allow the act of reading text to execute arbitrary code in the context of your brain. The same guarantees cannot be made for IDA Pro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended workflow is to make the initial database (idb) by running IDA within a VM. That way you are safe even in case of a possible zero day.

The idb file can then be taken out of the VM and analyzed elsewhere. The idb does not contain runnable machine code, so you are safe.

If you want to perform any dynamic analysis on the malware, you need to use a VM.

Comment: You could also ask [eset]( http://habrahabr.ru/post/124054/ ) about this ;)

Comment: Cool. I have a Windows XP VM (VirtualBox) so I should just be able to generate it, put it in a shared folder and remove the shared folder. Thanks!

Comment: as Viktor notes, VM escape is possible, too, so we cannot say "you are safe", only "less vulnerable".

Answer (score 0):

It's not dangerous as long as you're disassembling and not debugging. However, I strongly recommend you to use a VM

Comment: that's not entirely true - there have been bugs in IDA that can result in crashes just by opening the file.  It is entirely possible that some of them could have resulted in code-execution, in the right situation.

Comment: There have been VM escalation bugs. If this file is so extensive that it can run as an executable and exploit Ida... Maybe a VM won't help either.